# Print MS ACCESS table with while loop in VB.net

Tags: php, mysql, sql, vb.net

Like we can do easily in php with mysql we execute a query and then run a while loop on that to print all result records of that query. How do we perform this function in vb.net (2008) with ms access db. here is my code which I  use for printing now

```
sql = "SELECT * From Inventory "

        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Inventory")    
        Label1.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory").Rows(0).Item(2)
        Label2.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory").Rows(1).Item(2)
        Label3.Text = ds.Tables("Inventory").Rows(2).Item(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Dim rowCount As Integer = ds.Tables('Inventory').Rows.Count
Dim Labels() As Label = {Label1, Label2, Label3}

foreach label As Label In Labels

  label.Test = ds.Tables('Inventory').Rows(Array.IndexOf(Labels, label)).Item(2)

Next
```

Or if you want to get the `Labels()` array dynamically by getting all the Labels on your form, replace this with Line 2 of the above :

```
Dim Labels() As Label
For Each ctrl In Form1.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        nextNum = Labels.Length +1
        ReDim Preserve Labels(nextNum)
        TeamIndex(nextNum) = ctrl
    End If 
Next
```